# Passing data between pages?

Tags: php, mysql

I forgot how to do this correctly. I basically want one PHP page to send data to the database (submitscore.php) and another to grab them from the database and display them in a table (showscore.php):

submitscore.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['score']) && isset($_POST['playername']))
{
    $scorefromflash = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['score']);
    $namefromflash = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['playername']);


    $con = mysql_connect("servername","username","password");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Score) VALUES ('$namefromflash', '$scorefromflash')";

    header("./showscore.php");

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($con); 
}
?>
```

showscore.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("server","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);

echo ("Name: ".$namefromflash);
echo ("Score: ".$scorefromflash);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY Score DESC");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Score</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Score'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con); 

?>
```

I ask because doing this gives the error `Notice: Undefined index: score` and `Notice: Undefined index: playername` on the `submitscore.php` page.

It's not inserting any records into the database nor is it showing the table.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to store the data in the DB?

Comment: The mysql function are deprecated. Please take a look at PDO or mysqli. http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, that worked for me:

submitscore.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['score']) && isset($_REQUEST['playername']))
{
    $con = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("database", $con);    
    $scorefromflash = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['score']);
    $namefromflash = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['playername']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Score)
           VALUES ('$namefromflash', '$scorefromflash')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($con);

    header("Location: showscore.php");
}
?>
```

showscore.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY Score DESC");
if (!$result)
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Score</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Score'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

After inserting the data it redirects you to the page, where the table with all the data is shown. Change the database credentials. Here is the GET request, that I used for testing:

```
http://domain/submitscore.php?score=1&playername=2
```

Comment: why do he need $_REQUEST['playername'] & $_REQUEST['score'] as he just wanted to show the data from the database as per his question..

Comment: @santanukumar He is asking about the notice in submitscore.php. In this file he is inserting the data. That's why I used it.

Comment: but as per his question his intention is to show the database records and he is not aware of whether he need this two values for showing from database or not..

Comment: I'm just trying to send the name and score to the database and then show them in the table in the showscores.php page

Comment: @Liam I thought, you were asking about the notice. I saw, that you used my code. You will need to specify `id` of the inserted record to get the data in showscore.php from the database. You don't do it. That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

your `codes` are vulnerable to `sql injection` you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` function before inserting values into database..

you don't need

```
$scorefromflash = $_POST['score'];
$namefromflash = $_POST['playername'];
```

in show score page...

Comment: Updated with what I have now. It's not showing any errors but it's not showing the data from the database in the table either.

Comment: you are inserting data in ufoinvasion  but you trying to acess it using res table it should be SELECT * FROM ufoinvasion ORDER BY Score DESC in showscore.php.Also the database you selected during insertion is mysql_select_db("bg29li", $con); but you using mysql_select_db("testdb", $con); in showscore.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to set a header to reload the page back to showscore.php with the `$_POST['score'] and $_POST['playername']`

try this in submitscore.php:

```
header("location: ./showscore.php?player=$namefromflash&score=$scorefromflash");
```

and inside the showscore.php use:

```
$scorefromflash = $_REQUEST['score'];
$namefromflash = $_REQUEST['playername'];
```

Comment: why do he need to send $_REQUEST['playername'] & $_REQUEST['score'] as he just wanted to show the data from the database as per his question..

Comment: because he puts it there in a echo. I don't know why but if that is what he want let him.

Comment: Updated with what I have now. It's not showing any errors but it's not showing the data from the database in the table either. The `echos` were just to test that the variables were working.

Answer (score 0):

First: Your code isn't save. use something like `mysql_escape_string`

This isn't really an error. It is (like it says) a notice. you do not use the `isset` function to check if the variables are set. There is a possibility that this variables have no value, because the page before didn't send it.

if you use instead of

```
$scorefromflash = $_POST['score'];
```

use this:

```
$scorefromflash = isset($_POST['score'])?$_POST['score']:null
```

then this notice will be gone. also for other `$_POST` values

Comment: Updated with what I have now. It's not showing any errors but it's not showing the data from the database in the table either.